# add a command to tkinter button by a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to make a function which create a button with a command (action) on a window but I can't specify a self variable.

The function :

```
    def addButton(self,text,row,column,pady,action):

    action = "Window."+str(action)
    print(action)
    button = Button(self.Window, text=str(text), command=lambda:exec(action))
    button.grid(row=int(row),column=int(column),pady=int(pady),sticky=EW)
    self.buttons.append(button)
```

I'll be grateful if someone can help me

Comment: `getattr` is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr. Your question is unclear, so I can't help tell you exactly what to do, but you can use `getattr` to retrieve the callable object that you want to be your action. It would look *something* like: `action_obj = getattr(Window, action)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any python object you can use `getattr` to get an attribute by name. In your case you could use something like this:

```
func = getattr(self.Window, action)
button = Button(..., command = func)
```

There's no need to use `exec`, since in this case `getattr` will return a reference to a function (a *callable*), and the `command` attribute requires a reference to a function.